# Google Map Using SupportMapFragment and FragmentActivity Errors

Tags: android, google-maps

I am unfortunate to get into a 7-year-old code of Google Map which was still using V1 Map APIs. I am planning to change code make to at least for V2 (For now). So everywhere in StackOF I found this -

convert below -

> com.google.android.maps.MapActivity -->
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
>
> com.google.android.maps.MapView     --> 
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
>
> MapView.getController() and MapView.getProjection() and others  ---->
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap Object

Now Look at my code design -

Below is my XML File -

```
                      <com.my.own.package.GoogleMapView
                            android:id="@+id/googleMapView"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:enabled="true"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                            android:apiKey="XXXXX">
                       </com.my.own.package.GoogleMapView>
```

My GoogleMapView class looks like below -

> ```
> public class GoogleMapView extends MapHelperGoogleMapView implements ViewContextMenuHandler {}
> ```

And MapHelperGoogleMapView looks like below -

> public class MapHelperGoogleMapView extends SupportMapFragment {}

And Activity looks like below -

```
public class GPSInfoTabActivity extends MapBridgeMapActivity
{
   GoogleMap myMap;
   GoogleMapView googleMapView = (GoogleMapView) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMapView); // Question 1: Is this Casting correct ? Will this be properly casted ?
   googleMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
             gMap = googleMap; // Question 2: I want to use this gMap object to modify Map like markers, to be used in My GoogleMapView and MapHelperGoogleMapView both of class

         }
   });
   //registerForContextMenu( googleMapView ); Question 3: This Peice of code Needed ? It came from V1 code. 
}
```

There is a lot of Overlays, drawing and lof GeoPoints are being used, that part I can move only when I have access to GoogleMap object into my custom Classes.   But nothing is working as of now. Just can someone guide me on this. please comment if you have any question to understand my problem. thank in advnce.

Answer (score 0):

update your google map Gradle in **build.gradle**.

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the  element

```
       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Add this element in xml layout

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.android.app.MapsActivity" />
```

In Java code

```
public class GPSInfoTabActivity extends MapBridgeMapActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
} 

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap = map;

    }
```

Follow this reference [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) to get more.

Comment: Thanks for your Code but till this part, I am already done, the Only Question is How can I use myMap and mapFragments Object into my two class GoogleMapView and MapHelperGoogleMapView,  because they have a lot of logic old drawing, Canvas and getProjection, getController logic. Because You changed the XML file but there is no mention of com.my.own.package.GoogleMapView . which I put in my question because this file has a lot of logic.

Comment: could you please write here your code of GoogleMapView and MapHelperGoogleMapView? so I could give a suggestion on what you need to do.